# Displaying Map with Leaflet-Heat.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, leaflet

I am currently working on a web application where I'm trying to display a heat map using the library called Leaflet.heat. It works with the Leaflet Javascript library to create an overlay heat map that looks pretty good. I feel like I'm pretty much there but having one last bit of trouble with array format and can't figure out what is wrong. Let me share the code that I have right now.

```
    var mymap;
    var marker = [];
    var heatMapArr = [];
    window.onload = function() {
          alert("in initial func");
          uponPageLoadDefault();

        };
    function uponPageLoadDefault()
    {
        //initial default page load
        var branches = new L.LayerGroup();
        var items = JSON.parse('${branches}');
         var j = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
        {


           var LamMarker = new L.marker([items[i].lat, items[i].lon]);

           //GOT RID OF FUNCTION CALL.  
           var heatMapPoint = {
           lat: items[i].lat,
           lon: items[i].lon,
           intensity: items[i].tranCount
   };
          heatMapArr.push(heatMapPoint);


           LamMarker.bindPopup("<b>" + items[i].branchName + "</b><br>" + items[i].branchAdd + "</br><br>" + items[i].branchCity + "</br><br>" + items[i].branchSt + "</br><br>"  + items[i].branchZip + "</br><br>TranCount: " + items[i].tranCount).addTo(branches);
           marker.push(LamMarker);
    }
            mbAttr = 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
        mbUrl = 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoidGFzdHlicm93bmllcyIsImEiOiJjaXgzZWxkaHowMWZhMnlvd2wzNHllaGwxIn0.0RSZEhtR0OBLMbwjqFfBkg';

    var outdoors  = L.tileLayer(mbUrl, {id: 'mapbox.outdoors',   attribution: mbAttr});


    var heatmap = L.heatLayer(heatMapArr, {radius: 6, blur: 8,maxZoom: 8});

    var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [39.73, -104.99],
        zoom: 10,
        layers: [outdoors, branches, heatmap]
    });

    var baseLayers = {
        "Outdoors": outdoors
    };

    var overlays = {
        "Branches": branches,
        "HeatMap": heatmap
    };

    L.control.layers(baseLayers, overlays).addTo(map);
```

So basically I am trying to use the heat map display as a possible overlay that the user can select. The Leaflet-heat library tutorial is located at https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat/ and it explains what needs to be done in order for the library to work.

Anyway, I have a list of items with latitude, longitude, and intensity amount, so I'm trying to use that, its called items. I iterate through that, pushing the select information into my heat map array. At this point I should be almost all set besides adding the overlays and creating the map. When I run the program, the map displays but the overlay icon is absent so there is an issue.

In the website tutorial they use a separate Javascript file which has an array of objects to create their heat map. I tried this with my program and then everything worked, which quickly led me to believe there's a problem with my array of objects, probably some minor formatting thing.......I am using another function to create an object with the data I have, so it will be in the same format as the website example.

I tried to use alert and other statements and compare my array to theirs but it hasn't yielded anything useful so I wanted to post my issue here on Stack to get some feedback from others on what could be wrong. I think its something really small that I may not be seeing.

Any feed back is greatly appreciated and certainly let me know if there's any questions.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, it looks like I may have just answered my own question. Instead of calling a function to give me back an object item, I just did it the short hand way. I have edited the code and the program is now working with the heat map like I wanted, awesome!

Comment: Also deleted the function to create the object since its now unecessary.